# This is hard to say concisely...but I'm having issues with my if/else javascript. "if" won't happen after "Else" does

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I just started learning Javascript, so maybe this is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing, but this is what I think is a problem.

I have a text box and submit button. I have a `<p>` of text that is hidden.

IF the user's text entered is what I want it to be, the `<p>` of text shows on submit.

ELSE (any other user's text), the text shows up, but

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="Incorrect!";
document.getElementById("id").style.display="block;"
```

So, it works that if you enter the CORRECT word first, the `<p>` shows up.

If INCORRECT, it shows up, but with different text, ie, "incorrect!" So far, so good...

THE PROBLEM: After you get the text wrong, you can't try again, you have to refresh.
If you get it right, the right text shows, if you enter something else in after, the proper `<p>` follows, too, but if you try AFTER the wrong text is entered, it doesn't go back.

So once it's incorrect, you can't go back. So if someone got it wrong, and then put in the right word, they wouldn't be able to tell unless they refreshed and tried it again first.... Does this make sense? I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Well, you haven't posted any actual code, so there's nothing much to say.

Comment: Can you give us the offending code? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will let you create an entire example for us to review.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted much code so I'll make some assumptions in this answer, which I hope are clear

Say you have your "text box" `<input type="text" id="textbox"/>` which I'll call `box` and your message area `<p id="id">sometext</p>` which I'll call `msg`

```
var box = document.getElementById('textbox'),
    msg = document.getElementById('id');
```

Then in the code which handles the submit you have, say

```
if (box.value === 'foo') { // contains the right thing
    // ...
} else { // contains the wrong thing
    msg.innerHTML = 'Incorrect!';
    msg.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Which you say works fine the first time around, but not the second, then you'll need to consider what has actually changed between these two invocations? Perhaps you should re-set the defaults before the `if`, for example I'm guessing your message starts hidden, so you could add the following before the `if` line to make sure you're starting from where you expect

```
msg.style.display = 'none';
```